# find special characters in html with jQuery/JS

Tags: jquery, special-characters

Is it possible to use special characters, or their decoded html alternates within jQuery/JS?

In particular, why doesn't this work:

```
$("*:contains('™')", document.body)
```

nor this,

```
$("*:contains('&trade;')", document.body)
```

I need to hang a  on these TM marks, but there's nothing doing. In the document itself the ™ is present, not ™ (not my build. Just doing maintenance and goofs for this client).

Comment: Have you looked for previous questions in SO on this very topic?

Comment: This seems to work just fine for me.. http://jsfiddle.net/FBFgw/

Comment: It [works](http://jsfiddle.net/afTsc/). Probably the symbols are missing in the html code?